# Evaluating $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+e^{-x2^n})$

Tags: calculus, infinite-product, euler-product

In [this](http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html#InfinitexProducts) page, it is stated that
$$
\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+e^{-x2^n}\right) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\coth(x))
$$
How can one show this? In the webpage it is under the title "Euler's product", which I understand has something to do with representing the Riemann zeta function as an infinite product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One may recall that
$$
\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+z^{2^n}\right)=\frac1{1-z^2},\quad |z|<1, \tag1
$$ which may be proved by observing that
$$
(1-z^2)\prod\limits_{n=1}^N\left(1+z^{2^n}\right)=(1-z^{2^{N+1}}) \tag2
$$ then by putting $z=e^{-x}$ in $(1)$ ($x>0$) one may express $\dfrac1{1-e^{-2x}}$ in terms of $\coth x$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Did you mean the limit to be $\frac{1}{1-z^2}$?